# window['angularComponentReference'] is showing a type error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use NgZone on an Angular project:

```
constructor(
   private fishboneService: FishboneService,
   private zone: NgZone,
) {
  window['angularComponentReference'] = {
    zone: this.zone, 
    componentFn: (value: any) => this.getDataFromOutside(value), 
    component: this
  };
  console.log('reference added');
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not
> of type 'number'.
>
> 19     window['angularComponentReference'] = {

Comment: try change it `(value: any)` to `(value: number)`. I believe value should be a number.

Comment: It didn't worked but I solved setting "noImplicitAny" to false. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend your code with ts-ignore.
See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments

```
// @ts-ignore
window['angularComponentReference'] =
```